# Change Select Option based on Radio buttons

Tags: jquery, radio-button, selection

I want to select an option based on radio button. I tried the above code and many others, but it is not working. Can you please help me with this:

```
<input type="hidden" id="shippingrequired" name="shippingrequired" value="1">
<input id="shipping_shipping_standard" name="shipping_plugin" rel="GLS - platba dopredu" type="radio" value="shipping_standard" onclick="k2storeSetShippingRate('GLS - platba dopredu','5.5',0,0, '0', true );">
<label for="shipping_shipping_standard" onclick="k2storeSetShippingRate('GLS - platba dopredu','5.5',0,0, '0', true );">GLS - platba dopredu ( 5.50€ )</label><br>
<input id="shipping_shipping_standard" name="shipping_plugin" rel="GLS - dobierka" type="radio" value="shipping_standard" onclick="k2storeSetShippingRate('GLS - dobierka','5.5',0,1.2, '0', true );">
<label for="shipping_shipping_standard" onclick="k2storeSetShippingRate('GLS - dobierka','5.5',0,1.2, '0', true );">GLS - dobierka ( 6.70€ )</label><br>
<input id="shipping_shipping_standard" name="shipping_plugin" rel="Osobný odber - ZDARMA" type="radio" value="shipping_standard" onclick="k2storeSetShippingRate('Osobný odber - ZDARMA','0',0,0, '0', true );">
<label for="shipping_shipping_standard" onclick="k2storeSetShippingRate('Osobný odber - ZDARMA','0',0,0, '0', true );">Osobný odber - ZDARMA ( 0.00€ )</label><br>
<input type="hidden" name="shipping_price" id="shipping_price" value="0">
```

This is the RADIO button part.

This is the Selection box.

```
<select id="offline_payment_method" name="offline_payment_method">
<option value="Platba pri dodaní">Platba pri dodaní</option>
<option value="Bankový prevod">Bankový prevod</option>
</select>
```

I tried many solutions with jQuery, including, .prop, .attr, is(":checked") but none of them works.

My jQuery code:

```
$('input[rel*="dopredu"]').click(function() {
if($('input[rel*="dopredu"]').attr('checked')) { $('#offline_payment_method option:eq(1)').attr('selected','selected') }
});

$('input[rel*="dobierka"]').click(function() {
if($('input[rel*="dobierka"]').attr('checked')) { $('#offline_payment_method option:eq(0)').attr('selected', true) }
});

$('input[rel*="ZDARMA"]').click(function() {
if($('input[rel*="ZDARMA"]').attr('checked')) { $('#offline_payment_method option:eq(0)').attr('selected','selected') }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a fiddle please check it..[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/madhust/PEQ77/)

`$('input[rel*="dopredu"]').attr('checked')` will return string `checked` and hence changed the `if` condition as `$('input[rel*="dopredu"]').attr('checked') == "checked"` and also use `change` event for `radio` and `checkbox` instead of `click`.

```
$('input[rel*="dopredu"]').change(function() {
 if($('input[rel*="dopredu"]').attr('checked') == "checked") { 
         $('#offline_payment_method option:eq(1)').attr('selected','selected') 
   }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a function called whenever you click on a radio button and have that function select the corresponding option.